# How to use math.js in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to use math.js (https://mathjs.org/) in a Sencha ExtJS 6.2 application, classic framework.

I have tried

- Adding a script tag that references math.min.js in index.html.
- Configuring app.json file to reference math.min.js.

When running the application in Google Chrome, in Chrome Developer's Tools the file is shown to be loaded, however I cannot access the global variable math object, I get reference error.

How can I make it work with ExtJS?

Update:

It turns out that including the library in index.html under the body tag doesn't work for ExtJS for some reason. I'm not sure why, however including the library under head tag works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with any technology like Extjs. How have you loaded the file , if possible please share a code snippet and network console snippet.

Comment: How did you implement the library in your app.json file? And where did you try to access the global var?

Comment: @Tejas please read the question, I have put what I have tried in the question.

Comment: @stormtrooper: How are you accessing same library ?

Comment: @Kamun:  I added the reference to math.min.js in app.json, set it to remote so it will load the file in the application.

Comment: @Tejas: In Chrome's Developer tools, try to access the global variable math created by the library, and got reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your library math.js in index.html in head and then save math instance in a variable as below.

```
<script> 
var mathInstance = math;
</script
```

Ok, let's suppose that you want to use mathInstance in a file, then we will make our variable(math instance) global.
Put this on the first line in your extjs file:

```
/*global mathInstance*/
```

Now you should be able to use mathInstance and all methods anywhere you want.

Comment: It works, thanks, it turns out that including the library under body tag of index.html doesn't work in ExtJS for some reason, I'm not sure why, but putting the script tag under head works.